# Sync Local Folder to FTP

Tags: backup, ftp, filesystems, synchronization

I'm looking for an app I can put on my local server that will take files from C:\Source to a folder on my remote FTP Server every hour.

I was looking at rsync and it looked perfect until it told me I cant use my own FTP server. Any recommendations?

I'm going to have around 50,000 small files. nothing over 20kb, in the source folder, so the faster the ftp the better. Allway Sync is just too slow as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know two programs:

1. If you are willing to pay a little you have the **[FTP Synchronizer](http://www.ftpsynchronizer.com/)**
2. Also there is a free version of a similar program that is called **[BestSync](http://www.risefly.com/)**

I just found another one that looks good, however i've never used this: **[BatchSync FTP](http://maxlevel.com/batchsync.htm)**

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Looks like WinSCP and 'Watch Folder' might be my best bet so far.

Comment: of FileZilla, which is a great OSS project, with support for all the knows OSs.